# How to add metadata like UPC (Universal Product Code) and ISRC (International Standard Recording Code) to mp4 files using PHP?

Tags: php, mp4, meta-tags, ffmpeg-php

I am using php-ffmpeg for adding metatag on mp4 but it does not work for isrc and upc. While adding upc and isrc metatag on mp3, ffmpeg works fine. 
Code for adding metadata to mp4

```
$video = $ffmpeg->open(__DIR__ . '/audio.mp3');
        $format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
        $format ->setVideoCodec("libx264");
         $format ->setAudioCodec("aac");

        $video->filters()->addMetadata(["title" => "My songVideo", "artist"=>"artistVideo", "album"=>"AlbumVideo", "composer"=>"ComposerVideo4", "track" => "103","date"=>"2018","isrc"=>"us:1231123123","upc"=>"12325456"]);
        $format->on('progress', function ($video, $format, $percentage) {
            echo "$percentage % transcoded";
        });


        $format
            ->setKiloBitrate(1000)
            ->setAudioChannels(2)
            ->setAudioKiloBitrate(256);

        $video->save($format, 'video.mp4');
```